# Which are the config files for the built-in gnome-remote-desktop?

Tags: remote-desktop

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Trying to troubleshoot why the built-in remote desktop is unpredictable in providing access.

Where can I find the associated config files?

@user68186 No auto login. Normal user that is also in sudoers
The intention of this post is not to go and troubleshoot the remote desktop issues. I want to have a go at troubleshooting myself without having to bother the community. However it does help if I can have a look at the appropriate config.

I don't know how to make my question more clear than this:
I want to know where I can find the config files that govern the built-in remote desktop service.

Thanks,
Leo

Comment: Have you set up Ubuntu to auto login? Update your question with the answer.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you get a wrong password error? Do you get a black screen?